# pushViewController takes too long on Ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I have an annoying problem.

I use `Navigation Controller` to switch the `View Controllers`.
On my `iPhone` is going ok, but when i test on `iPad` it takes too much time(3-4 seconds) to push to second view controller.

In first View Controller

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    InGame *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"inGame"];
    vc.multiplayer = false;
    vc.methodStart = [NSDate date];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true]; });
```

In second View Controller `viewDidLoad` method

```
NSDate *methodFinish2 = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval executionTime2 = [methodFinish2 timeIntervalSinceDate:self.methodStart];
NSLog(@"executionTime = %f", executionTime2);
```

If it is important in second view I have 6 buttons some little images and a table with 17 rows. 2 buttons and 1 label per row.

Please, some little help.

EDIT!

That is happens just first time!

Here are images with threads

[image]

[image]

Comment: does it happens everytime or the first time ?

Comment: only the first time, i forget to specified

Comment: Does it happen when you attach the debugger ?

Comment: For release version too

Comment: The fact that you are calling `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue)` suggests that there is a lot more to this than you are telling us. In particular, you might be doing something on a background thread, or you might be doing some sort of networking. I would suggest that _that_ is what is taking the extra time. — In any case you can find out for sure what's going on just by using Instruments.

Comment: No, i do nothing in background. I calling dispatch_async just to avoid this answer and I do not using network in my app.

Comment: Don't wrap code in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` just "because" ... do it if you know it is the right thing to do. To figure out what's going on, you need to eliminate actions, then add them back in one-by-one till you hit whatever is causing the delay.

Comment: @Gaby Fitcal : Run your app in debug mode, do action to load second VC on iPad when its taking time pause the execution, you will see which action on main thread is blocking it :) Let us know will tell u the solution to fix it :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I just upload some screenshot for you